# issues with horizontal menu

Tags: html, css

I have a weird problem with my horizontal drop down menu. Please find the code below.

My HTML Menu part looks like follows -

```
<div id="page-wrap">
<ul class="dropdown">

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/home.png" border="0"></a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/aboutus.png" border="0"></a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/profile.png" border="0"></a>
             <ul id="submenu">
              <li id="firstItem"><img src="images/submenu_center_top.png"></li>
              <li><a href="#">Support Team</a></li>
              <li id="lastItem"><img src="images/submenu_bottom.png"></li>
             </ul>
            </li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/activities.png" border="0"></a>

         <ul id="sub_menu">

              <div><img src="images/submenu_center_top.png">
              <li><a href="#">Nutrition &amp; Tips</a></li>

              <div><img src="images/submenu_bottom.png"></div>
              </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/shiningstars.png" border="0"></a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/testimonials.png" border="0"></a></li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/gallery.png" border="0"></a>
         <ul id="sub_menu">

              <div><img src="images/submenu_center_top.png">
              <li><a href="#">Photo Gallery</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Audio Visual Gallery</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">In Press</a></li>

          <li><a href="#">Articles</a></li>

              <div><img src="images/submenu_bottom.png"></div>
         </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/eventsnews.png" border="0"></a>

         <ul id="submenu">

              <div><img src="images/submenu_center_top.png">
          <li><a href="#">Upcoming Events</a></li>

              <div><img src="images/submenu_bottom.png"></div>
             </ul>

        </li>

        <li><a href="#"><img src="images/contactus.png" border="0"></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
```

And my CSS file contains the following code:

```
#page-wrap {
 width: 1004px; margin: 0;
}
a {
 text-decoration: none;
}
ul {
 list-style: none; 
}
ul.dropdown {
 position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li {
 font-weight: normal; float: left; zoom: 1; /*background: #ccc; */
}
ul.dropdown a:hover {
 color: #fff;
}
ul.dropdown a:active {
 color: #ffa500;
}
ul.dropdown li a {
 display: block;
 padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
 /*border-right: 1px solid #333;
 color: #000;*/
}
ul.dropdown li:last-child a {
 border-right: none;
} /* Doesn't work in IE */
ul.dropdown li.hover, ul.dropdown li:hover {
 background: #1C1C1C;
 /*color: white;*/
 position: relative;
}
ul.dropdown li.hover a {
 color: black;
} /*LEVEL TWO*/
ul.dropdown ul {
 width: 200px;
 visibility: hidden;
 position: absolute;
 width: 100%;
 top: 100%;
 /*margin-left: -90px;*/
 left: 0; 
}
ul.dropdown ul li {
 font-weight: normal;
 font-size: 12px;
 background: #333333;
 color: #969696; 
 /*border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;*/
 border-left: 5px solid #969696;
 border-right: 5px solid #969696;
 /*float: left;*/
}
/* IE 6 & 7 Needs Inline Block */
ul.dropdown ul li a {
 border-right: none;
 width: 100%;
 display: inline-block;
} /*LEVEL THREE*/
ul.dropdown ul ul {
 left: 100%;
 top: 0;
}
ul.dropdown li:hover > ul { 
 visibility: visible; 
}
#firstItem, #lastItem {
 background: none;
 border-left: none;
 border-right: none;
}
.sub_menu {
 float: center;
}
```

I have been getting weird results both in IE 8 and Chrome too. The alignment is just not happening. Can somebody pleas ehlp? I am relatively new to HTMl and CSS.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Really, I like code, but that's too much.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: @tobaiasjl just install this chrome extension and its very easy to open any code in jsfiddle  https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stack-fiddle/loemajeogfdlphofpdfncpbbeoenmbpm

Comment: we cannot view the images because they are local to your machine. You'll need to host the images somewhere and do a jsfiddle

Comment: Rule #1 of menus - put all styling and hover on the A-tag, not the LI (other than positioning/float). Use display:none, not visibility:hidden.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of different things going on here.

The simplest answer for you though, for your alignment issues, is that your ul#sub_menu has padding.

Zero out the padding with this:

```
.sub_menu { padding: 0px; }
```

[Update:  Your html should use `class="sub_menu"` instead of `id="sub_menu"`.  Your html is invalid if you have more than 1 element with the same id]

A common practice these days is to start your CSS file with a bunch of "resets".  This will change the default padding and margin for a bunch of common tags to 0, so that you don't end up with spacing issues when you don't desire them.  For example, some resets I normally employ:

```
body, div, ul, ol, li, p, h1, h2, h3
{ padding: 0px; margin: 0px; }
```

**Other things that might help you, that I notice in your code:**

- `float: center` is not valid. The only valid values are: left, right, both, none, inherit
- `ul.dropdown ul ul` does not reference anything.  You only have 2 levels of ul, but this selector references 3 ul deep.  You probably got this CSS from a drop down menu example. If you don't need a 3rd level of drop downs, it's best to remove this CSS so as not to confuse yourself in the future.
- `visibility: hidden`, `visibility: visible`, I suggest using `display: none` and `display: block`.  The reason is, that `visibility: hidden` still takes up space on the page, even though it is invisible.  `display: none` however, does not render the DOM element at all, and it will not take up page space
- You have `<div>` elements as direct child elements of the `<ul>` tag in some of your sub-menu's.  Only `<li>` elements are allowed as direct children
- You have some elements named `sub_menu` and some named `submenu`.  You need to have consistent names if you want the styles to be applied correctly.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d5jKr/) with your code, and all the changes I mentioned.  I added width to your li and background colors to help see what was going on.

Comment: how do i create a fiddle for all of you to see how my menu works? sorry... but i am new to this....

Comment: It's alright.  Go to [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/) and put your html, css, etc. in appropriate box.  Click the "run" button on the top tool bar, and voila!

Comment: I edited my answer with some more fixes that I didn't notice the first time around.  I also added a jsFiddle link for you to view.

Comment: After the margins and alignments set properly for some weird reason the last drop-down option (Upcoming Events under Events / News main menu item) does NOT give me link to go to that page. Even if I hover over that option, there is no pointer cursor that allos me to click it to go to the desired webpage. What could be the reason? All other options are running very well, looking good but not this last drop-down link.

Comment: Not sure, have you edited the jsFiddle example above?  If so, I can look at your edited code, and see what the issue is.

Comment: The thing is that the code works well in the jsfiddle! when i went on to implement it in my html file, my earlier CSS code for the whole website (that includes paragraphing, color scheme for different elements etc.) must have meddled somewhere which I am not sure of. Should first check that I guess! Thanks!